# Как перенести элементы из одного массива в другой?

Tags: c++, массивы

Например,

```
k = 3 
arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

выносит

```
1,2,0,4,5
```

а я хочу, чтоб выносил:

```
1,2,4,5
```

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int a, b, c, k , n;


int main()
{
    int arr[5];
    int arr2[5];
    cin >> k;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] != k)
        {
            arr2[i] = arr[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << arr2[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотите этого?

```
for(int i = 0, j=0; i < 5; i++)
    if(arr[i] != k)
        arr2[j++] = arr[i];
```

Только когда будете выводить, не выводите все 5 элементов, как в вашем примере - у вас же столько не набирается :) Лучше так:

```
int a2_size = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    if(arr[i] != k)
        arr2[a2_size++] = arr[i];

...

for (int i = 0; i < a2_size; i++)
{
    cout << arr2[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

На языке С++ это будет сделать гораздо проще:

```
int* p = std::remove_copy_if(arr, arr + 5, arr2,  [&](int i) { return i == k;});
std::copy(arr2, p, std::ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```